# What is the notion for this arrow in category theory?

Tags: category-theory

When reading a CS paper, I encountered an arrow like $\langle f_1, \ldots, f_n \rangle : \langle A_1, \ldots, A_n \rangle  \rightarrow \langle B_1, \ldots, B_n \rangle$.  The author took it for granted to mean a collection of arrows $f_1 : A_1 \rightarrow B_1$, ..., $f_n : A_n \rightarrow B_n$.  I wonder if there is such a notion in category theory.  If it is, I would appreciate a reference.  Thanks.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you can regard it as being an arrow in the product category $C\times C\times\dots\times C$.

Comment: Ah, of course, thanks.  Unfortunately you did not put it into an answer.

Comment: There is not enough context to determine what your notation means. It would be helpful if you could give a precise reference.

Comment: @user1 Please promote your comment to an answer, as requested by OP.

Comment: In category theory, Cartesian products are bifunctors $\mathcal{C} \times \mathcal{C} \rightarrow \mathcal{C}$. So not only can we form the product $X \times Y$ for arbitrary objects $X$ and $Y$, but also the product $f \times g$ for arbitrary morphisms $f$ and $g$. Moreover, if $f_1 : X_1 \rightarrow Y_1$ and $f_2 : X_2 \rightarrow Y_2,$ then $f_1 \times f_2 : X_1 \times X_2 \rightarrow Y_1 \times Y_2$.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the information provided, the arrow $\langle f_1,\dots,f_n\rangle$ can be regarded as an arrow in the [product category](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_category) $\mathscr D=\mathscr C\times\mathscr C\times\dots\times\mathscr C$ if each arrow $f_i$ originates in $\mathscr C$.